# Colorbox, Iframe not working for me?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I've got a more complicated Colorbox but as a test I can't even get this to work.

What is wrong with my code? Have I missed something out?

**HTML**

```
<a class="cover" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">
    bbc
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cover").colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    innerWidth: 400,
    innerHeight: 400
  });
});
```

Comment: *html:bbc* doesn't really tell us much - need more html, in particular the snippet that uses the `.cover` class

Comment: Is that better? In this example all I want to do is open an iframe to  bbc website

Comment: yes, just to verify: you have the colorbox js loaded?

Comment: also: in your colorbox object - it's `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`

Comment: yes I took it from here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and took the colorbox-min.js one

Comment: did you make sure your code is inside the jquery ready() ?

Comment: yes its in the jquery ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code set in the jquery ready() event ?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".cover").colorbox({ iframe:true, innerWidth:"400px", innerHeight:"400px"});

  });
</script>
```

Comment: yup I did, sorry I should of put that in my question.

Comment: I think the purposes of this test that was what I was missing. I'll post my actual issue rather than my failed test. but that was it for this question. thanks!